# Is it possible to implement widgets using list in flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I am creating a Journal mobile application which would work as a medium to view magazines and daily news updates. This is my first flutter project and I am totally new to flutter. So kindly excuse me if I had said something wrong about something or didnt provide enough information.

I used a code from github for the main page of my application and made few changes to accommodate my needs. Now in my code, the home page consists of a side menu bar and this bar consists of 4 buttons, namely **Home**, **My Profile**, **Premium** and **FAQ**. The `GlobalKeys` for the side menu bar is called using a list by the name `_keys` which is of the type `GlobalKey`. I tried changing the data type of the list `_keys` to `Widget` and then called the corresponding `Widgets` of the classes. But then two errors popped out.

*The getter 'currentContext' isn't defined for the class 'Widget'.*

*The argument type 'Widget' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'GlobalKey<State>'.*

Now I would like the list `_keys` to be of the type `Widget` in order for me to call upon it's corresponding widgets of **Home**, **My Profile**, **Premium** and **FAQ** from each of it's classes in order for me to view the corresponding pages. Or if it is not possible, I would love to know an alternative for it to start working.

Following is the code of my application.

```
import 'dart:math' as math;

import 'package:flutter/scheduler.dart';
import 'package:google_signin_example/google%20sign%20in/logged_in_widget.dart';
import 'package:google_signin_example/main app/lib/ui_3/TravelBean.dart';
import 'package:google_signin_example/main app/lib/ui_3/magazine/screens/home_screen.dart';
import 'package:google_signin_example/main%20app/lib/ui_3/FAQ/faq.dart';
import 'package:google_signin_example/main%20app/lib/ui_3/Newspaper%20and%20Kiddos/lib_kiddos/main.dart';
import 'package:google_signin_example/main%20app/lib/ui_3/Newspaper%20and%20Kiddos/lib_news/main.dart';
import 'package:google_signin_example/main%20app/lib/ui_3/premium/premium.dart';
import 'package:google_signin_example/widget/sign_up_widget.dart';

import 'detail_page.dart';

class HomePage1 extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomePage1State createState() => _HomePage1State();
}

class _HomePage1State extends State<HomePage1> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      body: Container(
        child: Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            LeftWidget(),
            Expanded(
              child: RightWidget(),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class LeftWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _LeftWidgetState createState() => _LeftWidgetState();
}

class _LeftWidgetState extends State<LeftWidget> with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  List<String> _list = ["Home", "My profile", "Premium", "FAQ"];

  List <Widget> _keys = [                  
    HomePage1(),                           //These are the widgets from different classes.
    LoggedInWidget(),
    premium(),
    faq(),
    /*GlobalKey(),                         //This was available before I made the changes. 
    GlobalKey(),
    GlobalKey(),
    GlobalKey()*/
  ];

  int checkIndex = 0;

  Offset checkedPositionOffset = Offset(0, 0);
  Offset lastCheckOffset = Offset(0, 0);

  Offset animationOffset = Offset(0, 0);
  Animation _animation;
  AnimationController _animationController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    checkIndex = _list.length - 1;
    super.initState();

    SchedulerBinding.instance.endOfFrame.then((value) {
      calcuteCheckOffset();
      addAnimation();
    });
  }

  void calcuteCheckOffset() {

    lastCheckOffset = checkedPositionOffset;
    RenderBox renderBox = _keys[checkIndex].currentContext.findRenderObject();   //This is where the first error occurs.
    Offset widgetOffset = renderBox.localToGlobal(Offset(0, 0));
    Size widgetSise = renderBox.size;
    checkedPositionOffset = Offset(widgetOffset.dx + widgetSise.width,
        widgetOffset.dy + widgetSise.height);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            width: 50,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Color(0xff000000),
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
            ),
            child: Column(
              children: _buildList(),
            ),
          ),
          Positioned(
            top: animationOffset.dy,
            left: animationOffset.dx,
            child: CustomPaint(
              painter: CheckPointPainter(Offset(10, 0)),
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  List<Widget> _buildList() {
    List<Widget> _widget_list = [];

    _widget_list.add(Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(
        top: 50,
      ),

      child: Icon(
        Icons.settings,
        color: Colors.white,
        size: 30,
      ),
    ));
    for (int i = 0; i < _list.length; i++) {
      _widget_list.add(Expanded(
        child: GestureDetector(
            onTap: () {
              indexChecked(i);
            },
            child: VerticalText(
                _list[i],
                _keys[i],                                        //This is where the second error occurs.
                checkIndex == i &&
                    (_animationController != null &&
                        _animationController.isCompleted))),
      ));
    }
    _widget_list.add(Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(
        top: 50,
        bottom: 50,
      ),
      child:  Image(image: AssetImage('assets/images/Voix.png')),
    ));
    return _widget_list;
  }

  void indexChecked(int i) {
    if (checkIndex == i) return;

    setState(() {
      checkIndex = i;
      calcuteCheckOffset();
      addAnimation();
    });
  }

  void addAnimation() {
    _animationController =
        AnimationController(duration: Duration(milliseconds: 300), vsync: this)
          ..addListener(() {
            setState(() {
              animationOffset =
                  Offset(checkedPositionOffset.dx, _animation.value);
            });
          });

    _animation = Tween(begin: lastCheckOffset.dy, end: checkedPositionOffset.dy)
        .animate(CurvedAnimation(
            parent: _animationController, curve: Curves.easeInOutBack));
    _animationController.forward();
  }
}

class CheckPointPainter extends CustomPainter {
  double pointRadius = 5;
  double radius = 30;

  Offset offset;

  CheckPointPainter(this.offset);

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    Paint paint = Paint()..style = PaintingStyle.fill;

    double startAngle = -math.pi / 2;
    double sweepAngle = math.pi;

    paint.color = Color(0xff000000);

    canvas.drawArc(
        Rect.fromCircle(center: Offset(offset.dx, offset.dy), radius: radius),
        startAngle,
        sweepAngle,
        false,
        paint);

    paint.color = Color(0xffffffff);
    canvas.drawCircle(
        Offset(offset.dx - pointRadius / 2, offset.dy - pointRadius / 2),
        pointRadius,
        paint);
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(CustomPainter oldDelegate) {
    return true;
  }
}

class VerticalText extends StatelessWidget {
  String name;
  bool checked;
  GlobalKey globalKey;

  VerticalText(this.name, this.globalKey, this.checked);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return RotatedBox(
      key: globalKey,
      quarterTurns: 3,
      child: Text(
        name,
        style: TextStyle(
          color: checked ? Color(0xffffffff) : Colors.grey,
          fontSize: 16,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class RightWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _RightWidgetState createState() => _RightWidgetState();
}

class _RightWidgetState extends State<RightWidget>
    with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  TabController _tabController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _tabController = TabController(vsync: this, length: 5);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      margin: EdgeInsets.only(
        left: 15,
      ),
      child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: <Widget>[
          Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 50, left: 20),
            child: Text(
              "Voix Home",
              style: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.black,
                fontSize: 25,
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 15, left: 10),
            child: SizedBox(
              height: 30,
              child: TabBar(
                isScrollable: true,
                unselectedLabelColor: Colors.black,
                labelColor: Color(0xffffffff),
                controller: _tabController,
                indicator: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Color(0xff9e9e9e),
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                    topRight: Radius.circular(20),
                    bottomLeft: Radius.circular(20),
                  ),
                ),
                tabs: <Widget>[
                  Tab(
                    text: "Flash",
                  ),
                  Tab(
                    text: "Magazine",
                  ),
                  Tab(
                    text: "Newspaper",
                  ),
                  Tab(
                    text: "Kiddos",
                  ),
                  Tab(
                    text: "Editorial",
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: TabBarView(
              controller: _tabController,
              children: <Widget>[
                TravelWidget(),
                HomeScreen(),
                News(),
                Kiddos(),
                RightBody(),
               // RightBody(),
              ],
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class RightBody extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      margin: EdgeInsets.only(
        left: 15,
      ),
      color: Colors.white,
      child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: <Widget>[
          Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(
              top: 20,
            ),
            child: Text(
              "Flash!",
              style: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.black,
                fontSize: 20,
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: ListView(
              scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
              children: <Widget>[
                Container(
                  width: 220,
                  margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                    horizontal: 10,
                    vertical: 10,
                  ),
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(40),
                    image: new DecorationImage(
                      image: new AssetImage('assets/images/bottom1.jpg'),
                      fit: BoxFit.cover,
                    ),
                    boxShadow: [
                      BoxShadow(
                        spreadRadius: 5,
                        blurRadius: 5,
                        offset: Offset(1, 2),
                        color: Color(0x33757575),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                Container(
                  width: 220,
                  margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                    horizontal: 10,
                    vertical: 10,
                  ),
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(40),
                    boxShadow: [
                      BoxShadow(
                        spreadRadius: 5,
                        blurRadius: 5,
                        offset: Offset(1, 2),
                        color: Color(0x33757575),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class TravelWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  List<TravelBean> _list = TravelBean.generateTravelBean();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return PageView.builder(
      controller: PageController(viewportFraction: 0.9),
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        var bean = _list[index];
        return GestureDetector(
          onTap: () {
            Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) {
              return DetailPage(bean);
            }));
          },
          child: Hero(
            tag: bean.url,
            child: Stack(
              children: <Widget>[
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 30, right: 10),
                  child: ClipRRect(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
                    child: Image.asset(
                      bean.url,
                      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                      fit: BoxFit.cover,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Positioned(
                  bottom: 80,
                  left: 15,
                  child: Column(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Material(
                        color: Colors.transparent,
                        child: Text(
                          bean.location,
                          style: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.black54,
                            fontSize: 15,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      Material(
                        color: Colors.transparent,
                        child: Text(
                          bean.name,
                          style: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.black,
                            fontSize: 20,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                Positioned(
                  bottom: 0,
                  right: 30,
                  child: Container(
                    width: 60,
                    height: 60,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: Colors.black,
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
                    ),
                    child: Icon(
                      Icons.arrow_forward,
                      color: Colors.white,
                      size: 30,
                    ),
                  ),
                )
              ],
            ),
          ),
        );
      },
      itemCount: _list.length,
    );
  }
}
```

At the beginning, when I leave the list `_keys` to be of the type `GlobalKey` and don't comment out the following 4 `GlobalKeys` I get the output but the side menu bar won't work.

[This is my application with `GlobalKeys` in place of those `Widgets`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tiFXY.gif)

I want those corresponding pages to display when clicked on. But that render object just switches between the options and the same page is displayed.

So kindly help me out.

PS : As said earlier I'm new to flutter, so kindly don't mistake me if I had something wrong.

Comment: Hi, what do you want to do in a nutshell?

Comment: Hi @IvánYoed . My priority over here is to display the sidebar pages when clicked on the options. But I am not able to do it as I don't know how to call the corresponding page's widgets. Could you help me out?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you check about flutter state management, especially Mobx with Provider, it will be kind easier for you.